# InternetExplorer programatically handling popup with C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, popup

I'm using the `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` object to navigate through a website programatically using `C#`. The problem is, that the website is divided in 3 parts, with each part being a separate window/popup:

1. Login Screen
2. Confirmation Screen (popup #1)
3. Actual Application (popup #2)

I'm already using the `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` object for enterering the credentials and clicking the login buton on the first screen. But I dont know, how to get a handle to the second-screen (popup #1) in order to be able to click the confirm button on popup #1. Same problem applies for third screen (popup #2). I noticed the `IE_NewWindow2`-event of `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. The first parameter should be according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa768287(v=vs.85).aspx) a new `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` object, but it's actually `null`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get a list of the active IE browser and then identify the instance you are looking for by name.

```
 SHDocVw.ShellWindows Windows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass();
    foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in Windows)
    {

    }
```